# Do I run an install or something for Ajax on windows 2008 R2 hosting web application?

Tags: ajax

I have an application that runs fine on windows 2003 environment with Ajax panels, checking to see if when I move this application to a new windows 2008 server R2, would I need to install the Ajax toolkit and then the Ajax minifier on the server itself?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are developing on the server itself, no you will not need them installed on your server as they just help generating code.